# Irregular migration files for two one-to-one relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations, one-to-one

I have three classes that are supposed to split a concept into 3 tables on one-to-one basis. Literally, a huge table that I want to chunk up.

```
class MainHolder
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public FirstPart FirstPart { get; set; }
  public SecondPart SecondPart { get; set; }
}
class FirstPart
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
}
class SecondPart
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I'm setting up the context and relations as follows.

```
public DbSet<MainHolder> Holders { get; set; }
public DbSet<FirstPart> FirstParts { get; set; }
public DbSet<SecondPart> SecondParts { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder model)
{
  model.Entity<FirstPart>()
    .HasOne<MainHolder>()
    .WithOne(a => a.FirstPart)
    .HasForeignKey<MainHolder>();
  model.Entity<SecondPart>()
    .HasOne<MainHolder>()
    .WithOne(a => a.SecondPart)
    .HasForeignKey<MainHolder>();
}
```

When I create a migration, the main holder contains 2 columns - first with ID of itself and one with the ID of the second entity **but** not the first one. The foreign keys are set up as expected: it's just the columns that are incomplete.

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(name: "Holders", columns: table => new
{
  Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
  SecondPartId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: true)
},
constraints: table =>
{
  table.PrimaryKey("PK_Holders", x => x.Id);
  table.ForeignKey(
    name: "FK_Holders_FirstParts_Id",
    column: x => x.Id,
    principalTable: "FirstParts",
    principalColumn: "Id",
    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
  table.ForeignKey(
    name: "FK_Holders_SecondParts_SecondPartId",
    column: x => x.SecondPartId,
    principalTable: "SecondParts",
    principalColumn: "Id");
});

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(name: "FirstParts", columns: table => new
{
  Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
  Title = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false)
},
constraints: table => { table.PrimaryKey("PK_FirstParts", x => x.Id); });

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(name: "SecondParts", columns: table => new
{
  Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
  Description = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false)
},
constraints: table => { table.PrimaryKey("PK_SecondParts", x => x.Id); });
```

I notice a slight difference in the setup of the FK's in naming and cascade strategy. I can't for the life of me explain why this happens since both entities are declare and configured precisely the same way.

What am I missing?

If it's due to some convention for managing multiple has-one/with-one tables, then I failed miserably to find any kind of documentation on that. I fear that there actually is a deviation and I'm simply to dense to realize it. Help me understand.

Comment: Try removing the `.HasForegnKey` I think EF may be getting confused by this expecting a unique FK on the MainHolder for each relationship and using the default ID for the first case and generating one for the 2nd. By default a 1-to-1 relationship will be established between the PKs on both tables, which looks to be the way you are setting things up and expecting, So just having the `HasOne.WithOne` defined for both should work as expected.

Comment: @StevePy I will do that later today. Although, while I see how you figure, I expect your suggestion to only affect the naming and, possibly, definition of the FK. I can't see how it actually would affect the columns created in the table. On the other hand, if my prediction is wrong, I'll be just happy. :)

Comment: HasForeignKey is normally used in 1-to-1 relationships where you want to nominate a separate FK on one side for the relationship.  For example if you wanted a FirstPartId on the MainHolder rather than joining the two on the PK. The default behaviour is to use the PKs on both tables. The other change I would suggest is to define the 1-to-1 relationships from the MainHolder perspective rather than from both First and Second. I.e. `Entity<MainHolder>().HasOne(x => x.FirstPart)....`  and `Entity<MainHolder>().HasOne(x => x.SecondPart)....`

Comment: @StevePy Well, in the end, it didn't let me skip the FK method. However, you got me on the right track and you were sort of right. Since I declared the FK pointing to the main holder's table from both parts' tables, it couldn't make it. When I turned that around treating the latter as dependent, it skipped the columns with FK all together (which actually makes even more sense).

Comment: @StevePy I'd like to ask you for two things at this point. One: please post the comments' contents as a reply to be accepted as an answer. Two: please elaborate on the suggestion to move the fluent API specs from perspective of the main holder. (I'm not objecting - in fact, I prefer that. But it's still good to have some kind of reasoning explicitly stated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `.HasForegnKey()`. I think EF may be getting confused by this expecting a unique FK on the `MainHolder` for each relationship and using the default ID for the first case, then generating another one for the 2nd. By default a 1-to-1 relationship will be established between the PKs on both tables, which looks to be the way you are setting things up and aiming for. So, just having the `HasOne().WithOne()` defined for both should work as expected.

`HasForeignKey()` is normally used in 1-to-1 relationships where you want to nominate a separate FK on one side for the relationship. For example if you wanted a `FirstPartId` on the `MainHolder` rather than joining the two on the PK. The default behavior is to use the PKs on both tables.

The other change I would suggest is to define the 1-to-1 relationships from the `MainHolder` perspective rather than from both `FirstPart` and `SecondPart`.

So instead of:

```
model.Entity<FirstPart>()
  .HasOne<MainHolder>()
  .WithOne(a => a.FirstPart)
  .HasForeignKey<MainHolder>();
model.Entity<SecondPart>()
  .HasOne<MainHolder>()
  .WithOne(a => a.SecondPart)
  .HasForeignKey<MainHolder>();
```

use:

```
model.Entity<MainHolder>()
  .HasOne(a => a.FirstPart)
  .WithOne();
model.Entity<MainHolder>()
  .HasOne(a => a.SecondPart)
  .WithOne();
```

The rules around support for optional bi-directional navigation properties are somewhat fluid with EF Core, so the `WithOne()` may not work as expected without a reference for `MainHolder` on the `FirstPart` and `SecondPart`. A work-around is typically to add a `protected` (or possibly `private`) reference if EF Core complains. 1-to-1 relationships commonly benefit from having bi-directional references where a `MainHolder` contains a reference to the `FirstPart`, and a `FirstPart` contains a reference back to its `MainHolder`. That navigation property does not need a `ForeignKey` attribute or mapping defined when part of a one-to-one relationship.